# How to split structured text files in multiple text files in python 3

Tags: python, regex, text, split

I am trying to use re in Python 3 to split my structured text files into multiple ones. this is the structure of the text file

```
Debates

Content 

 ======================= #there is a space in the front of this line

Debates

Content 

 ======================= #there is a space in the front of this line
```

I would like to obtain something like

```
1.txt 
Debates
Content 
 =======================

2.txt
Debates
Content 
 =======================
```

and so on

This is the code that I am trying to use

```
import re

data=open("file.txt", encoding="utf-8")
data=data.read()

found = re.findall(r'\n*(Debates.*\s\n\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=)\n*', data, re.M | re.S)
[open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w').write(found[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(found)+1)]
```

Python does not give me any kind of error but it seems to freeze when I try it. 
Does anyone know how to do that? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=`: really ?

Comment: thanks for letting me understand that I made a mistake! Nevertheless, is currently less than a month that I am using Python and actually learning whatever deals with programming... So my answer to you is YES really! :)

Comment: It isn't a mistake since it's correct, but when you see something fastidious like that, it's often a sign that there's an easier way.

Comment: Tnx for this! I got the point of the "easier way" as indicated in the solutions below that do make sense to me, but actually python keeps giving me UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)  :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use regex then I would suggest this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = file.read().split(' =======================\n')[:-1]
for i, debate in enumerate(data):
    with open(str(i+1) + '.txt', 'w') as dfile:
        dfile.write(debate)
```

Comment: Nice use of the .split(). I would close the input file after reading it, though.

Comment: @RobinKoch I use `with` statement so `file` will be closed automatically.

Comment: I know, but only after all the other files are created. I suggest to dedent the for loop. There is no reason to keep the file handle after reading the file. Also the indention level would be one less.

Comment: @RobinKoch fair enough. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this.

```
(\bDebates.*?\n\s={23})
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/ZQCR62/1

Use `re.DOTALL` and no other flags.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Nevertheless it keeps giving me this mistake UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Bene den u need to open it file using codecs and correct encoding

Answer (score 0):

1. In your RegExp there is a newline in front of the equal signs, that might be the reason it doesn't match.
2. You don't need to escape the equal-signs.
3. The stream of equals-signs is written more compact as `={23}` which matches, well, 23 equal-signs. You also can put a `$` behind it to mark the end of the line: `={23}$`
4. and most important: your quantifiers are greedy, trying to match as much as possible. So your first `.*` matches the entire files up to the last separator line. If you wanna have multiple matches use the question mark: `.*?` which tries to match as little as possible.
5. And as mentioned before: RegEx isn't the best way to go in this situation.

Nevertheless my working code:

```py
import re

with open("file.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

found = re.findall(r'(Debates.*?={23})', data, re.M | re.S)

[open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w').write(found[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(found)+1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried this solution but it keeps giving me this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128) I think the problem is the = sign...

Comment: @Bene, probably no. The problem is in position 34. In the sample you posted that's in the middle of the first row of equal signs. But there's no `\xa0` character present. Maybe you should inspect/provide the original file (or at least the first 40 bytes of it).